# Assigning a method to a generic property

Tags: c#, oop, generics, .net-4.0, delegates

I am trying to design a class that will be flexible enough to chart data about different kinds of data.  I'm new to OOP in C#, so I'm fumbling around trying to achieve this using some combination of generics, delegates and classes.

Here's the class that I've written so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Charting
{
    public class DataChart<T>
    {
        public Func<T, object> RowLabel { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here's how I'm trying to call it:

```
var model = new DataChart<MyClass>()
{
    RowLabel = delegate(MyClass row)
    {
        return String.Format("{0}-hello-{1}", row.SomeColumn, row.AnotherColumn);
    }
};
```

The problem with this approach is that I'd have to explicitly cast the object emitted by **RowLabel**.  I was hoping I could somehow make the output type a generic and add constraints to it, like so:

```
    public class DataChart<T>
    {
        // The output of the RowLabel method can only be a value type (e.g. int, decimal, float) or string.
        public Func<T, U> RowLabel where U : struct, string { get; set; }
    }
```

Is this possible?  And if so, how do I do it?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: The design for `RowLabel` looks a little weird. I just wonder how `RowLabel` is called in your program, since they have different return value types? Maybe there are possibilities to refine the design?

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure there's room to refine things... I'm not even done building stuff out.  I just want to know if some of the ideas I come up with are even possible.

Comment: If RowLabel is function that provides label for row it should return string shouldn't it?

Comment: I know the property is named **RowLabel**, but it's the approach to this question that I was curious about.  There are cases where I'd want to render something besides a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do *some* of this.

First, genericizing the output: just add another type parameter to the class.

```
public class DataChart<T, U>
{
  public Func<T, U> RowLabel  { get; set; }
}
```

But those type constraints you mentioned do not make sense. Type constraints are "and"-ed, not "or"-ed. A `string` is not a `struct`, so you can't confine it to that specific combination of types. It will still work if you leave it unconstrained, although you lose some compile-time safety.

Edit: Also, it turns out you can't specify `string` as a type parameter, anyway. It's a sealed class! Having a generic that only accepts types of a sealed class would be pointless, and the compiler prevents it.

Comment: I don't want to specify U at the class level, so this exact approach won't work.  But knowing that type constraints are AND-ed is helpful & makes sense.

Worst-case, I'll just declare the **RowLabel** property as `Func<T, string>` and call it a day -- after all, it's easy to represent value types as strings.  Also, I suspect what I'm looking for is support for generic properties, which I'm reasonably certain is not in .NET 4.

Comment: Generic properties are most definitely not supported.